# Edit FASTA header

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

I want to remove part of the header of all my sequences in a fasta file, so only the Otu number appears as the header.

So from:

```
>M02300_51_000000000-CJMTC_1_1115_17014_15334   Otu0001  
T-AC--GG-AG-GGT---GCA-A-G-C--G-T-T--AA-T-CGG-AA--TT-A-C-T
```

I would like to change it to:

```
>Otu0001  
T-AC--GG-AG-GGT---GCA-A-G-C--G-T-T--AA-T-CGG-AA--TT-A-C-T
```

I believe this should be possible with the sed command but haven't been able to make it work. Any help would be great! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know anything about the structure of FASTA, but if the substring `Otu` cannot appear anywhere else in the header, then

```
sed 's/^>.*Otu/>Otu/' file.fasta
```

should do it

Comment: Thank you very much! That's worked perfectly!!